# How to understand & control the order of items in shown in an iteration on a delivery plan

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

If you re-order items on a backlog, the board magically also moves tickets/PBIs around. Backlog priority/order changes however do not appear to influence the order of items in the new Delivery Plans 2.0. Any guidance on how DevOps is ordering items in the Deliver Plan iteration and hence how to control this would be very helpful.

The tip here doesnt appear to be true - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops#interact-with-a-plan

Thank you